# How to get current BDD step in QAF?

Tags: java, testng, qaf

I'm writing a custom report in QAF and I want to pass the current BDD step with parameters into my custom report. I'm looking to implement both inside StepDefinition code and listener.

I have tried the below code inside Step Definition.

```
TestBaseProvider.instance().get().getContext().getProperty("current.teststep")
```

**EDITED:**

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "Test step")
public void testStep() {
    System.out.println("===CURRENT Test Step ===> "+ 
    getBundle().getPropertyValue("current.teststep"));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
===CURRENT Test Step ===> current.teststep
```

Answer (score 0):

`current.teststep` property will return step currently under execution or last completed one if no step in execution state. You can use [step listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#teststep-listener).

If you want to create custom reporting, best way is to implement [TestCaseResultUpdator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/integration_with_other_tools.html) interface. Here you can find few reporting [examples](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/tree/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/report) with TestCaseResultUpdator implementation.

**EDIT:**
similar to the example in question, below code works fine for me:

```
    @MetaData("{'isSetup':true}")
    @QAFTestStep(description = "Test Step-1")
    public static void step1() {
        TestStep step = (TestStep) TestBaseProvider.instance().get().getContext().getProperty("current.teststep");
        Map<String, Object> metadata = step.getMetaData();
        Reporter.log("metadata: " + metadata);
    }
```

In example above meta-data is optional, just added to demonstrate additional meta-data feature, available with step. Here is report:
[image: step report]

Again, **this is not right way for reporting**. For reporting either step listener or result listener should be used.

Comment: Can I use getBundle().getPropertyValue("current.teststep"); inside step definition?

Comment: you can, but keep in mind that the value will be step currently under execution or last completed step if no step in execution state.

Comment: Please check the above edit. I'm getting the output as "current.teststep", not "Test Step"

Comment: try `TestStep step = (TestStep)TestBaseProvider.instance().get().getContext().getProperty("current.teststep")`. If it is dryrun mode it may be null. BTW while you are inside step, why you want step object? because inside step you you already know step name, args etc... If purpose is step reporting then it's bad idea to write reporting code inside step.